# Airflow quickstart not working

Tags: python, airflow

Hi I've just started using Airflow, but I cannot manage to make the task in the quickstart run: `airflow run example_bash_operator runme_0 2015-01-01`.

I've just created a conda environment with python 2.7.6 and installed `airflow` through `pip` which installed `airflow==1.8.0`. Then I ran the commands listed here https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/start.html.

When I try to run the first task instance, by looking at the UI nothing seems to happen. Here's the output of the command:

```
(airflow) ✔  se7entyse7en in ~/Projects/airflow  $ airflow run example_bash_operator runme_0 2015-01-01
[2017-07-28 12:06:22,992] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
Sending to executor.
[2017-07-28 12:06:23,950] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
Logging into: /Users/se7entyse7en/airflow/logs/example_bash_operator/runme_0/2015-01-01T00:00:00
```

On the other hand the backfill works fine: `airflow backfill example_bash_operator -s 2015-01-01 -e 2015-01-02`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that if a single task is ran then it is listed under `Browse > Task Instances` as part of any DAG.

Answer (score 0):

The run command is used to run a single task instance.
But it will only be able to run if you have cleared any previous runs.
To clear the run:

- go the Airflow UI(Graph View)
- Click on the particular task and click **Clear**

Now you will be able to run the task with the cmd that you initially had.

To view the logs for this task you can run:
**vi /Users/se7entyse7en/airflow/logs/example_bash_operator/runme_0/2015-01-01T00:00:00**

I had a task like:

```
t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep',
    depends_on_past=False,
    bash_command='sleep 35',
    dag=dag)
```

I was able to see the changes in the state of the task as it was getting executed.